# In Powershell Use -replace or .replace To Change TD value to a Link

Tags: html, xml, powershell

I am trying to generate HTML reports of data collected in Powershell. I want to eventually have the HTML link to more specific information about the different elements in the table. In particular, the first column contains names of Virtual Machines, but this isn't particularly important. I am attempting to replace the name value with a link.

```
 for($i=1; $i -le $xml.table.tr.Count-1; $i++){
 $xml.table.tr[$i].td[0].replace($xml.table.tr[$i].td[0],"<a href=`"http://stackoverflow.com`">myLink</a>")
 }

  $file = Join-Path C:\users\myname\Documents "VMSpecs.html"

  ConvertTo-Html -Title "VM Specs" `
  -CssUri C:\Users\myname\Documents\style.css `
  -Body $($xml.InnerXml) | Out-file $file


 Invoke-item $file
```

Based on the output, the value of $xml.table.tr[$i].td[0] is being replaced with the link information but not permanently. When the file is written to HTML the link information is nowhere to be found, and the original value is still held in the td el

So,big picture, I would like to know how to append a link into html -fragment at a particular location. Any samples or resources be much obliged.

Comment: How are you writing the results back?

Comment: Currently it prints the link to console for every td[0]... if I add $xml.table.tr[$i].td[0] =    before the call to replace there is no output to console and also $xml.table.tr[$i].td[0] does not change

Comment: Provide more code please...

Comment: What I meant to say is I tried what KevinD has suggested and the content is not being replaced.. I added the final portion of the code which converts to html and invokes the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both .Replace and -replace produce a new string. What you'll want to do is reassign the results:

```
for($i=1; $i -le $xml.table.tr.Count-1; $i++){
  $xml.table.tr[$i].td[0] = $xml.table.tr[$i].td[0].replace($xml.table.tr[$i].td[0],"<a href=`"http://stackoverflow.com`">myLink</a>")
 }
```

Although, in this particular case, there doesn't seem to be any need for the replace at all. Since you're replacing the entire content of the td, just directly assign it:

```
 for($i=1; $i -le $xml.table.tr.Count-1; $i++){
  $xml.table.tr[$i].td[0] = "<a href=`"http://stackoverflow.com`">myLink</a>"
 }
```

I initially misread your question as being about replace, rather than assigning to a node. It looks like when you get a particular element as above, PowerShell is converting it to a string, so you're not actually updating the node. Try this instead:

```
 for($i=1; $i -le $xml.table.tr.Count-1; $i++){
  ($xml.table.tr[$i].GetElementsByTagName("td") | Select-Object -First 1)."#text" = "<a href=`"http://stackoverflow.com`">myLink</a>"
 }
```

The "#text" property may vary, I'm not sure. I did a test with a very simple HTML file, and by doing a Get-Member on each level of the resulting XML object, I found that that was the property I needed to update.

Hmmm ... okay, try this. Create a new XML element containing the link, and append it to the td element:

```
for($i=1; $i -le $xml.table.tr.Count-1; $i++){
  $link = $xml.CreateElement("a")
  $link.SetAttribute("href", "http://stackoverflow.com")
  $link.InnerText = "myLink"
  $xml.table.tr[$i].FirstChild."#text" = ""
  $xml.table.tr[$i].FirstChild.AppendChild($link)
}
```

Comment: Yeah i tried this as well, but still just the initial content of the td is still there after html is Invoked...

Comment: Im realizing a direct assignment is not working at all and perhaps this the root of my problem, that is $xml.table.tr[$i].td[0] = "anything" just simply isn't working; the content is remaining the same.

Comment: yeah it works as I wanted too but doesn't create the link like i hoped but rather just the text of the link. I will have to look a bit more into XML parsing techniques

Comment: Huh. I hadn't realized it would escape the html. I just updated my answer to include creating a new XML element for the link, and then adding it to the td node.

Comment: awesome! this inherently answers many of my questions on how I can manipulate PS data to become an interactive "website." Thanks!

Comment: Excellent! I'm glad I was able to help. Plus, I learned a bit more about handling XML in the process.